# pygame images not loading?

Tags: python, image, pygame, loading

How come my Goku sprites aren't loading my left and right image appear correct but my others aren't playing in motion? the mian thing am trying to accomplish is for my character images to work correctly in motion
below is the code with a link to the full code description:

https://pastebin.com/umMJHNQj

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()#We always need to initialize our pygame IN EVERY PROJECT/FILE

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))# Here win is representing "window" for our screen which we have set at 500 by 480

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")#We are giving our Window/Screen a name

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('image/gokuR0.png'), pygame.image.load('image/gokutest2.png'), pygame.image.load('image/gokuR2.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('image/gokuL0.png'), pygame.image.load('image/gokutest.png'), pygame.image.load('image/gokuL2.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('image/bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('image/goku sprite - standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = False
```

Here is where i have tried to alter the code but yet no results.

```py
def draw(self, win):
    if self.walkCount + 1 >= 8:
        self.walkCount = 0

    if not self.standing:
        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 100], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 100], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
    else:
        if self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
        else:
            win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
    pygame.display.flip()
    print(walkLeft)
    print(walkRight)
```

```
class projectile():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
```

All these images are working correctly yet can't seem to get my main characters images to work in properly in motion

```py
class enemy():
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load("image/R1E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R2E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R3E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R4E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R5E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R6E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R7E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R8E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R9E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R10E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R11E.png")]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load("image/L1E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L2E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L3E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L4E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L5E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L6E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L7E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L8E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L9E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L10E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L11E.png")]
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.walkcount = 0
        self.vel = 3

    def draw(self,win):
        self.move()
        if self.walkcount + 1 >= 33:
            self.walkcount = 0

        if self.vel > 0:
            win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkcount += 1
        else:
            win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkcount += 1
    print(walkLeft)



    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkcount = 0

        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkcount = 0



def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    goblin.draw(win)
    man.draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()


# mainloop
man = player(200, 400, 85, 85)
goblin = enemy(100, 400, 64, 64, 450)
bullets = []
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if man.left:
            facing = -1
        else:
            facing = 1

        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(
                projectile(round(man.x + man.width // 2), round(man.y + man.height // 2), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing))

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    else:
        man.standing = True
        man.walkCount = 0

    if not (man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: format code because it is unreadable

Comment: as for me images are loaded but your logic doesn't work as you expect and it never use loaded images. Simply use `print()` to see values in variables OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: Dang it thought I did format it properly?!

Comment: instead of `blockquote` use `code sample` (button `{}`) for all code - it will better format it and use colors. Your current `walkRight = ..` is incorrectly formatted - it display some code in one line but it should display in two lines.

Comment: code is long and complex - to resolve problem it would be debuged. You can do it using debuger or simple using  `print()` - to see values in different variables in different moments. This way you will see if it works as you expect.

Comment: Could you take a look at the link and maybe guide me on where to fix my code?

Comment: to answer for your question I would have to use `print()` with different variables in different places to see how code works. But you can do it on your own - and learn how to search problem in code.

Comment: I have edited the code please take look at it one more time still can't seem to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `self.walkCount` is (integral) divided by `100`:

> ```py
> win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 100], (self.x, self.y))
> ```

Note `self.walkCount` will never become grater than 7, because of:

> ```py
> if self.walkCount + 1 >= 8:
>    self.walkCount = 0
> ```

So the result of `self.walkCount // 100` is always 0.

Anyway this code makes no sense, since `walkLeft` and `walkRight` are lists containing 3 images. I recommend to do the following:

```py
def draw(self, win):
    walkfps = 10

    if self.standing:
        self.walkCount = 0
        if self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
        else:
            win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))

    elif self.left:
        if self.walkCount // walkfps >= len(walkLeft):
            self.walkCount = 0 
        win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // walkfps], (self.x, self.y))
        self.walkCount += 1

    elif self.right:
        if self.walkCount // walkfps >= len(walkRight):
            self.walkCount = 0 
        win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // walkfps], (self.x, self.y))
        self.walkCount += 1
```

If the images change to rapidly, then increase `walkfps`.

Comment: it works thanks! could you explain what I was doing wrong in my code though? or why it wasn't working the way I wanted it too?

Comment: @RalphPerez I have explained that in the 1st section of the answer. `self.walkCount` is < 8 and so `self.walkCount // 100` is always 0